# Using Fourier Transform to speed up calculation of forces following an inverse square law

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, na.numerical-analysis, fourier-analysis, algorithms, approximation-algorithms

Suppose I have $n$ electric point charges in, say, two dimensions.  Is there any algorithm (and I have a hunch that it might be related to the Fourier transform) to compute the net forces that act on each point charge in less than $O(n^2)$, preferably something like $O(n \log n)$?  Thanks!

An approximation might be good enough for my use case.

Comment: First hit on google: http://www.cs.montana.edu/courses/spring2005/580/papers/0906008.pdf

Comment: This could be also a good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_simulation#Calculation_optimizations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FFT is an important part of the [fast multipole method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_multipole_method), which is probably what you would want to use.

Comment: NB. http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.4114 appears to describe a more manifestly Fourierish FMM.